# XCode 4.2.1 - Problems with va_list, va_start, va_end from SFML 2.0

Tags: xcode4, variadic-functions

There are a couple of problems here. First, including cstdarg throws this error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cstdarg:59:11:{60:9-60:11}: error: no member named 'va_list' in the global namespace [3]
   using ::va_list;
```

Then, including c++locale.h throws this:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/c++locale.h:76:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'va_start' [3]
     va_start(__args, __fmt);
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/c++locale.h:84:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'va_end' [3]
     va_end(__args);
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cstdarg:54:20: note: instantiated from:
 #define va_end(ap) va_end (ap)
```

I'm not sure what to do about this. I'm using SFML 2.0, and including Graphics.hpp from it gives these errors. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem. I discovered that having both `/usr/local/include/**` and `/usr/include/**` in my header search path broke all of the standard template libraries.  One of the libraries I was using installed its self in `/usr/lib` and `/usr/include`, I found that uninstalling this library and reinstalling it to `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include` solved the problem.

I tried including `stdio.h` as suggested above, but it did not help.

The system I am using is Mac OS 10.8 and XCode 4.3

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on a project and fixed it by adding an additional include at the start that takes care of loading in the missing element:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

If you look in that file you see the definition:

```
#ifndef _VA_LIST
#define _VA_LIST
/* DO NOT REMOVE THIS COMMENT: fixincludes needs to see:
 * __gnuc_va_list and include <stdarg.h> */
typedef __darwin_va_list    va_list;
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain C headers are not compatible with C++ ones. Try including `cstdarg` instead of `stdarg.h`

Comment: Thanks, that produces the same error though. It looks like XCode automatically calls cstdarg if you include stdarg.h

Comment: No way. First, it's not Xcode which is doing it, it's the C preprocessor. Second, it will thus include whatever you requested.

Comment: I see, well it's interesting that it's happening